# Is mAh a universal rating?

Tags: battery

When looking at laptop specs, I noticed that some laptops (such as mine) have a battery measurement of around 4500mAh at 10.7v. Now, I've got a power bank that's 13000mAh at 3.7v.

I have several questions:

Now, how would I calculate how long each one would last? And which one would last longer under the same draw? Is my battery pack just much denser than my laptop battery? (my laptop was mid 2011, and the power bank is 2015)

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question might be a good place to start: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/1478/49251

Comment: @Gregd'Eon wow, that's a lot to take in. Mind explaining? I've kinda got the jist, but I'm still pretty confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how much circuits knowledge you have, but I'll dive in.

A milliamp-hour rating tells you how long your battery will last if you know how much current you're pulling out of the battery. As an example, if you were drawing 3 amps from your first battery, it would last for

T = 4500 mAh / 3 A = 1.5 h

or 90 minutes. Similarly, your second battery will last 260 minutes at this current.

However, your two batteries have different voltages, and this means that the same *power* will cause different *currents* in the two batteries. This is because P = IV, so a battery with more voltage will supply less current to produce the same power.

Let's take our example one step further. If your laptop is consuming 30 watts of power, then your first battery would be supplying

I = 30 W / 10.7 V = 2.8 A

and we can calculate its lifetime like we did above, finding a lifetime of 96 minutes. Likewise, your second battery pack would supply 8.1 A and last for 96 minutes.

You can make this more complicated - electronics might be more efficient at one voltage level than another, and a battery doesn't have the same voltage while it's draining - but this is a good estimate.

Comment: Superuser users: I wrote this answer for EE:SE, so I hope it's appropriate for this site.

Comment: Yeah, it's well formatted and everything. Good explanation, if a better one doesn't arise, i'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: also, if I were to use a step up converter with an efficiency of around 75%, how would I calculate how long the power bank would operate at 10.7v?

Comment: @Hellreaver First, figure out the power output. Then divide by 0.75 to get the power input. Then figure out the power capacity of the battery (current capacity times voltage).

Comment: If you're working at an efficiency of 75%, that means only 3/4 of the power your bank supplies is useful. Since the power your laptop consumes hasn't changed, that means your bank supplies 4/3 the original power. Is that enough info?